# WebLogic Application Server (10.3.6) fails with Large sized ear file deployment, critical CSRF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, atg

I am working on an ATG project, tried to deploy an ear file of 650MB size(ATG libraries consuming lot of size) on weblogic 10.3.6 on windows 7.
via admin console which is single and stand alone AdminServer (my localhost),  Getting a warning on my eclipse console

Critical Console BEA-240005 A Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) has been detected. Task=com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.uploadApp address=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 user=weblogic>

and my deployment fails. How to deal with oversized deployables? I appreciate your help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you determine that the CSRF is caused by a large ear?

Comment: What happens if you create a bare minimal app with all the same library dependencies and deploy that... do you see the same error?

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, and Kevin. My deployment is unsuccessful and all I noticed is that CSRF message on my eclipse. When I tried with a minimal size ear, I am able to goto next step but see application related warnings on admin console such as "Exception in AppMerge flows' progression", missing ....etc.

Comment: If I were you I think I'd try and get a minimal ear/war deployed first so you know everything's good, and then incrementally add back your app. If you're getting errors with even a minimal app then something else is up. Those warnings though, are they causing the deploy to fail, or does the app deploy ok and initialize? Weblogic is very verbose in it's startup console/log output and some warnings you might just ignore.

Comment: Going back to the ATG libraries... is there any recommendation to deploy them as shared libraries on the server itself, and then that way you wouldn't need to package them inside your EAR?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=ecql3ejla_101&_afrLoop=397749670922150#SYMPTOM

Bug 13688111

Fixed in: 12.1.2
CAUSE
WebLogic server allows file uploads of size lower than 250 MB. When an uploaded file doesn't match this requirement, issue is being rediscovered: the process is terminated and treated as a Cross-site request forgery (CSRF).

This is explained in the unpublished defect: 13688111
SOLUTION
Limit has been raised to 2GB on file uploads